# How to create horizontal bar stack and align the labels differently

Tags: javascript, graphics, d3.js

I need to create a chart using  D3.jswith the  following layout

[image: D3 Stackbar]

As you can see, my is any difficulty in placing the labels properly aligned (the left and right corners of the bars respectively)

As far as I could get ...

```js
var cxNext, data, height, labelScale, margin, parentHeight, parentWidth, percentScale, svg, width, xScale;

parentWidth = document.body.clientWidth;

parentHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

margin = {
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0
};

width = parentWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

data = [{
  label: "PRODUCT 1",
  percent: 0.5
}, {
  label: "PRODUCT 2",
  percent: 0.5
}];

xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]).domain([0, 100]);

labelScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function(p) {
  return p.label;
})).rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

cxNext = 0;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.cx = cxNext;
  return cxNext = xScale(d.percent * 100);
});

percentScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.percent * 100 + "%";
})).rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr({
  width: width + margin.left + margin.right,
  height: height + margin.top + margin.bottom
});

svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data).enter().append("rect").attr({
  "class": "bar",
  width: function(d) {
    return xScale(d.percent * 100);
  },
  height: height,
  x: function(d) {
    return d.cx;
  },
  y: function(d) {
    return 0;
  },
  fill: function(d, i) {
    return "rgb(0, " + ((i + 10) * 15) + ", 0)";
  }
});

svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - 40) + ")").call(d3.svg.axis().scale(labelScale));


/*
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis percent")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height-65) + ")")
    .call d3.svg.axis().scale(percentScale)
 */
```

```css
.bar:hover { fill: green; }

.axis {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  fill: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.percent { font: 20px sans-serif; }
.axis path, .axis line { fill: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Would you not simply need to set the position to the edge of the bar and `text-anchor` appropriately?

Comment: How to do this? each text must be aligned differently (one for right and another on left). 

Another detail, how to apply anchor in axis?

Comment: Well what exactly do you want? Your picture has bars and labels, no axis? Also, you have three scales, but use only one of them. What are they meant for?

Comment: I use two scales. The third is an attempt to put the % values (See comment code).   

In the picture are just texts, if done with axis labels or text or whatever does not matter. Since the first text is aligned to the right of the first bar and the following left.

Comment: Here's a quick demo http://jsfiddle.net/k979tet7/

Comment: Exactly what we wanted!
Could you help me on a last detail, adding a padding these labels? 
I tried with `startOffset` but without success.   http://jsfiddle.net/k979tet7/1/

Comment: You need to add/subtract those values from the coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/k979tet7/2/

Comment: Thanks! If you want to register as response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have exactly two bars, it's easy -- all you need to do is set the coordinates and text anchor depending on whether it's the first or second label:

```
svg.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text").attr({
  x: function(d, i) {
    return i == 1 ? d.cx + 10 : xScale(d.percent * 100) - 10;
  },
  "text-anchor": function(d, i) {
    return i == 1 ? "start" : "end";
  },
  y: height - 10
}).text(function(d) { return d.label ; });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k979tet7/2/).